# MySQL: Finding Orphan Records best practices

Tags: mysql

What are the best practices for writing a query to search for Orphan records?

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible (except for inserting 'table_name' as a value).

Comment: you'd have to create all your tables to have either the same number of columns or less but not exceed a maximum. That way it could work out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to insert a table name dynamically. However, it sounds like you're wanting to define a view, instead of a table. You could do something like this, though:

```
CREATE VIEW `orphaned_tables` (`table_name`, `id`) AS
    SELECT 'TABLE_A', id FROM TABLE_A
        WHERE /* Check if table a's id is orphaned */
    UNION
    SELECT 'TABLE_B', id FROM TABLE_B
        WHERE /* Check if table b's id is orphaned */
    UNION
    ...
```

By creating it as a view, you won't have to worry about inserting data; when you select it, it will always have the table name *and* orphaned IDs.